# List of good-to-know derivatives and integrals

Tags: reference-request, integration, derivatives

Can someone link me to an exhaustive list of notable derivatives/integrals?

For example, for $y= [\ln(x)]$, $\quad y^\prime = \dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: "Exhaustive" is hard when "notable" is so subjective.

Comment: Notable is not that subjective. See the example. You know have a general idea of what I mean with notable.

Comment: Try wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules).

Comment: That word "subjective," I don't think it means what you think it means. Or maybe you don't know what "exhaustive" actually means.

Comment: How about "Handbook of Mathematics" by Bronstein et al., http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:ISBN-Suche/3540434917? Alternatively, just check Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know what you meant, you meant that what might be notable to me, might not be notable to you. And with exhaustive I mean all of the special cases (which appear frequently), and what is considered a 'special case' is pretty universal.

Comment: For example, the example you gave is a special case of the chain rule, $(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ where $f(y)=e^y$ and $g(x)=\ln x$, using that $(e^y)'=e^y$ and $(x)'=1$. Note, one example is not even close enough for us to determine a pattern.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If it's too unclear for you to comprehend, don't worry, icurays1 gave me some pretty satisfying lists :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [Handbook of Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540721215) (Bronshtein), for many, many of your reference needs.

You'll also want to know [derivatives of trig functions](http://www.math.brown.edu/UTRA/trigderivs.html); see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions) for differentiation of trig functions.

You might also want to include in your list derivatives of inverse trig functions and hyperbolic trig functions, as well. Here is a list of such functions and their derivatives and integrals: [downloadable in pdf](http://www.coastal.edu/mathcenter/HelpPages/Handouts/invhyp.PDF).

Of course, you'll also want to know $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)$.

I'm assuming you've got polynomials down pat.

Here is a very nice and handy handout from "[Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)": [Common_Derivatives_and_Integrals.pdf](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Common_Derivatives_Integrals.pdf).

The rest is largely a matter of knowing how to differentiate products and compositions of such functions (using chain rule, e.g.).

I wouldn't consider the list exhaustive, but it's a start!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)!